# Commenting on locked questions requires 1 reputation?

Tags: bug, comments, locked-questions

On locked questions and answers ([example](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/61142/167443)), the "add comment" button is disabled. Makes sense, since commenting is disabled on locked posts. However, it indicates a requirement of 1 reputation to be able to comment:

[image]

Since 1 reputation *does not* allow you to comment a locked post, can this be removed?

Comment: Probably the same bug as this http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/190180/requires-50-reputation-to-comment-on-deleted-posts

Comment: That question also explicitly mentions "requires 1 rep on meta"

Comment: Since this is the same bug, probably should close this one as a dup so we keep all of the discussion for it in the same place?

Comment: It is the same bug, but obviously a different scenario - thanks for reporting it.