# Close Votes review shows "requires 1 reputation" text next to the "add comment" link

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, review

In the Close Votes review queue, if there is a votes to close as exact duplicate, then the "Duplicate" tab shows "requires 1 reputation" text next to the "add comment" link.

**Duplicate tab:**

[image: Screenshot of the Duplicate tab]

**Normal post:**

[image: Screenshot of normal post]

Comment: Probably leftover/side effect of [this one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/190180/152859)

Comment: This happens to questions in on First Posts (when the post in question is an answer) and Late Answers as well.

Comment: taking a look...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for reporting.

This has been fixed and will be out in the next build.